# this refers to global object despite using .bind(this)

Tags: javascript

I am confused regarding how to work with `this` in combination with `bind`. I know the problem stems from `this` being the global object. Could somebody explain how I could circumvent?

In the constructor I have done this:

```
var BoundedStartTimer = this.StartTimer.bind(this);
var BoundedStopTimer = this.StopTimer.bind(this);
var BoundedClearTimeString = this.ClearTimeString.bind(this);
BoundedClearTimeString();
```

The last one works, but the timer does not start when I call `BoundedStartTimer();`.

I am not sure what I am doing. Below are my declarations:

```
MemoryGame.prototype.StartTimer = function(){
  var playTimeInMilliseconds = 0;
  this.timeString = "";
  this.timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    if(playTimeInMilliseconds >= 1000)
      this.timeString = .....
    this.handleToTimerText.textContent = this.timeString;
  }, 10);
}

MemoryGame.prototype.StopTimer = function(){
  clearInterval(this.timer);
}

MemoryGame.prototype.ClearTimeString = function(){
  this.handleToTimerText.textContent = "00:000";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is with your `setInterval` call. `setInterval` executes functions in the global scope, meaning that `this === window` which is not ideal. You were right that `bind` can work here though, just bind the interval callback to `this`:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  if(playTimeInMilliseconds >= 1000)
    this.timeString = .....
  this.handleToTimerText.textContent = this.timeString;
}.bind(this), 10);
//     ^ bind this from your MemoryGame instance to the interval callback
```

Comment: Thank you @Travis J. The timer started. But why doesn't BoundedStopTimer() stop it?

Comment: @LasseKaragiannis Could you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com/) with your full JS code? That would make testing easier.

Comment: @Xufox Thank you, but I am new to webprogramming, I don't really know how to do it i JSFiddle, I am using a vagrant-server from the labs. I've constructed an example code on pastebin, with one button and one span element, just to have something concrete to discuss around for this question of "this" with bind. It  adds one button, and one span element to the DOM. When clicking the button, the textContent of span element is "incremented", counting seconds, and when button clicked again the timer is stopped.
http://pastebin.com/wfx3Us6J

Comment: @LasseKaragiannis Hm, alright, I actually just wanted to test what `this` is inside the `MemoryGame.prototype.StopTimer` function — the global object or the desired object. Because `this.timer` could be `undefined` if `this` refers to the wrong object and then the resulting `clearInterval(undefined)` wouldn’t do anything.

Answer (score 2):

So here's the deal.

**Every time** you see the keyword `function`, you should think two things.

First is, "oh, this creates a new scope for variables!" Lots of people from Java think this happens with each curly brace `{` that is not used as an object literal; that's false, it's only a `function` context (or, now with ES6, there is `let` and `=>` that do it too.)

The second thing you should think is, "oh, probably `this` and `arguments` are going to be different in the new variable scope." That's because these two keywords are especially "magical" in JavaScript.

So when you write:

```js
this.timer = window.setInterval(function () {
    if (playTimeInMilliseconds >= 1000) {
        this.timeString = .....
    }
    this.handleToTimerText.textContent = this.timeString;
}, 10);
```

...you **have to** see that `function` as a new variable scope with its own `this` and `arguments`.

Now, `playTimeInMilliseconds` is going to be **fine** if you don't at any point in *this* function write `var playTimeInMilliseconds`, which will get "hoisted" to the top of the function declaration and declare a new variable local to that scope. As long as you never do this, `playTimeInMilliseconds` will peek at the parent variable scope and find the variable you defined in the outer scope.

However, `this.timeString` and `this.handleToTimerText` are **not fine** because the value of `this` was declared to be `window`.

There are two remedial approaches:

1. In the outer function, *capture `this` into your own variable*. Common variable names for this purpose are are `me` and `self`. Just write `var self = this;` in the outer function, then **do not** write `var self` in the inner function, then write `self.timeString` and `self.handleToTimerText`.
2. Take the function and explicitly `.bind()` it. So pull out the function like so:

   ```js
   function updateTimerText() {
       if (playTimeInMilliseconds >= 1000) {
           this.timeString = .....
       }
       this.handleToTimerText.textContent = this.timeString;
   }
   this.timer = setInterval(updateTimerText.bind(this), 10);
   ```

Obviously, `bind` has a lot of power! So **don't do crap like this**:

```js
var BoundedStartTimer = this.StartTimer.bind(this);
var BoundedStopTimer = this.StopTimer.bind(this);
var BoundedClearTimeString = this.ClearTimeString.bind(this);
BoundedClearTimeString();
```

I have no idea what scope this stuff is occurring in, but it's probably not in the right scope. Because whatever you're binding as `this` has to be the instance of `new MemoryGame()` that you created --  maybe let's say you called it `var myMemoryGame = new MemoryGame();` or so; just use `myMemoryGame.startTimer()` (or whatever) and let the `this` come naturally. Whenever you write `a.b.c.d.e()` the `this` in the context of function `e()` is magically set to `a.b.c.d`. Don't reassign it to `this` unless you know what the heck you're doing and that you have to preserve `this` in some new context. At the very least be nice to readers and `.bind(myMemoryGame)` so that it's 100% clear.

Comment: I didn't get everything. English, is not always clear to  me... Could you please try to explain, why did BoundedClearTimeString(); work but neither this.StopTimer(); or BoundedStopTimer();
Greatful for help

Comment: If `BoundedClearTimeString()` works but `BoundedStopTimer()` does not, then the problem is not with `this` scoping. Possibly you should inspect the console for errors in your code. Maybe there are no errors: For example, during the rest of the code do you ever calculate `playTimeInMilliseconds`? The only assignment to that variable appears to assign it to `0`. Or for example, do multiple things call `BoundedStartTimer()` without `BoundedStopTimer()` in the middle? If they do, then you will clobber `this.timer` with the second `start` and then you will never `clearInterval()` the first timer!